# Nested greedy quantifier not matching

Tags: php, regex, regex-greedy

I have noticed some strange behaviour with a PCRE regular expression I can't explain.  I would expect the code:

```
preg_match('!^.+?(?:/programs/([^?#]+))?.*?$!',
    'http://example.com/programs/drive', $matches);
```

to return "drive" as match 1.  The `[^?#]+` and the `?` after the non-capturing group are both greedy so why doesn't the `[^?#]+` take precedence and match `drive`? Instead testing revealed that the `.+?` at the start matches the `h` and the `.*?` at the end matches the rest of the URL.

By contrast, the code:

```
preg_match('!^.+?(?:/programs/([^?#]+).*)?$!',
     'http://example.com/programs/drive', $matches);
```

works as expected and returns `drive` as match 1.

Comment: @hwnd I assume only matching URL's that don't have a query string or hash, or only the components before those characters.

Comment: @hwnd: No, it matches either zero or one time, as much as possible. Which is greedy.

Answer (score 3):

Whats happining is this. The first `.+?` is applied at the start of the string before the `h` in `http`. This is lazy so it gives up right off the bat and the `(?:/programs/([^?#]+).*)?` is tested against the `h`. This whole expression is optional so it, too, gives up after failing to match at the start of the string. Finally, the `.*?$` at the end of the pattern is applied, and this expression is able to match all the characters in the string for a successful match.

Comment: *+1*. This is what I thought after seeing the [regex101 debugger](http://regex101.com/r/cI6uL0), but my regex-fu wasn't strong enough to be indeed sure that this was the case. One doubt though, why does `(?:/programs/([^?#]+).*)?` fail? I'm assuming this is because the regex engine, while at the `h` position, cannot find `/programs/` after it. Or is it something else? It seems to work if I replace `.+?` with `http://example.com` in the expression.

Comment: Nice, ridgerunner! +1

Comment: @Amal Murali - The `(?:/programs/([^?#]+).*)?` expression fails because the text it matches _must_ start with a forward slash - which is not present at the `h` at the beginning of the string.